# My laptop's integrated speakers and microphone stop working when I plug headphones in

Tags: linux, arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio

When I plug some headphones in the 3.5mm jack port of my laptop, the integrated speakers and microphone stop working.

I uploaded the whole output of `pactl list` on pastebin:

- With the headphones NOT plugged in (internal speakers and microphone work): https://pastebin.com/QbhDmY6s
- With the headphones plugged in (internal speakers and microphone do NOT work): https://pastebin.com/sDP6rw9F

The difference is in the Ports of "Sink #0", "Source #1" and "Card #1": those about the internal speakers and microphone become "not available" when headphones are plugged in.

This issue started this week. Last week I was able to use the integrated microphone while listening through the headphones. It happens both with 3-pin jacks and 4-pin ones.

**How can I further debug the issue and figure out what's wrong?**

Software and hardware used: the latest Arch Linux with Pulseaudio 14.2, KDE Plasma 5.21.5, Linux 5.12.6-arch1-1 on an x86-64 Lenovo Thinkpad E495 (AMD Ryzen 5 3500U).

Comment: Surely this a feature, not a bug?

Comment: @JeremyBoden: my headphones don't include a microphone. I'd like to be able to use the integrated microphone while listening through my headphones. Preventing me from doing this for no reason is definitely not a feature.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is not with PulseAudio, but with lower level systems: the Linux's HD-Audio Driver.

I'm assuming that recently I upgraded the HD-Audio Driver (`snd-hda-intel`) or the codec for my chip (Conexant CX8070) and the new version chooses to disable the integrated peripherals when something is plugged in the jack connector.

I did find some sort of solution with help from the [ArchLinux Multimedia and Games forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1975573#p1975573): by setting the `auto_mic` hint for my codec, the integrated microphone is no longer disabled (and the headphones one is not enabled) when the headphones are plugged in.

This solution is very hacky though as it's hard to change. I'm still hoping to find a way to choose which microphone to use through the PulseAudio interface, like I used to.